# Access to Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Ubuntu Workstation 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 12.04. I gave the server a static IP address. I now installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a workstation. I can connect to it via the terminal but I cannot add any folders to the server. When I connect via SSH with the correct creditenals and static IP address, it gives me the following message:

```
Error while creating directory Folder. There was an error creating the directory in sftp://(name). The permission status is: Permission denied.
```

I would like to know how I can give full-editing access to the workstation user (different static IP address) so they can edit the server files.

Thank you.

Comment: According to the error you tried to use sftp, not ssh

Comment: but when I connected to the server I did the following:
server: ip address
type: ssh